# Conversion of Array

Tags: import

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => abc
            [title2] => xyz
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => abc2
            [title2] => xyz2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => abc3
            [title2] => xyz3
        )

)
```

convert this to

```
 Array
(
     [title] => abc
     [title2] => xyz
),
Array
(
    [title] => abc2
    [title2] => xyz2
),
Array
(
   [title] => abc3
   [title2] => xyz3
)
));
```

Comment: Hi Darshna some help of you $name_of_array =  (array) $name_of_object;

Comment: so you want to create three  different arrays ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Magento question but a PHP only question.